# Custom Controller Find By not ID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I create a custom details to search not by id, but by a certain witch would contain the following attributes.

Here I have a model call Menu, and Inside I have the following attributes

```
ID
Title
Link
```

I know I can details the following ways

```
Details(int id)
{
Menu menu= db.Menus.Find(id);
}
```

However I expect this to be a string

like `localhost/about`

I know I have to create a custom routes, which I can do however I don't know how to find by link with the string. Here my attemps but it fails

```
Details(string link)
{
Menu menu= db.Menus.Find(link);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`LINQ`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b):

```
public ActionResult Details(string link)
{
    Menu menu = db.Menus.FirstOrDefault(m => m.SomeProperty == link);
    ...
}
```

Where `SomeProperty` is obviously the property on your model that you want to be comparing against. The `FirstOrDefault` extension method will return `null` if no element is found that matches the specified criteria. So it's up to you to handle this case.